# Отключение функции у кнопки при втором клике

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Я хочу сделать так чтобы при втором клике на кнопку не работала функция на js связанная с этой кнопкой, но я не знаю как это сделать без добавления атрибута disabled. Найти в интернете не получилось.

Comment: можно преобразовать функцию в генератор `function* abc(var i=0){i++; if(i==1){/* here you code */}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте переменную флаг, что бы проверять, можно ли запускать функцию или нет.
Например можно сделать вот так:

```
let flag = true;
function clickBtn() { // Ваша функция клика по кнопке
    if (flag) {
        // Устанавливаем флаг, что бы не работало при повторном клике
        flag = false; 
        
        // тут ваш код функции
        
        // Возвращаем флаг по окончанию работы
        // или по какому либо другому условию
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш код