# Как реализовать debounce?

Tags: javascript

надо было написать функцию debounce, которая должна принимать функцию и время задержки, а возвращать модифицированную функцию.
Пример:

```js
let counter = 0;
const fn = () => {
  counter++;
};
 
const debouncedFn = debounce(fn, 200);
debouncedFn(); // первый вызов
setTimeout(debouncedFn, 100); // вызов через 100 мс после последнего вызова
// первый вызов был заблокирован, второй ожидает окончания таймера
setTimeout(debouncedFn, 200); // вызов через 100 мс после последнего вызова
// второй вызов был заблокирован, третий ожидает окончания таймера
setTimeout(debouncedFn, 300); // ...
setTimeout(debouncedFn, 400); // после этого вызова не следует других вызовов
// только этот вызов сработает, т.к. после него прошло 200 мс и других вызовов не было
console.log(counter); // 1
```

Мой код:

```js
const debounce = (fn, debounceTime) => {
    let count = -Infinity;
    let res;
    return function() {
        const end = Date.now();
        if (end - count >= debounceTime) {
            count = end;
            res = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        return res;
    };
};
```

Не проходит тест "должна блокировать вызовы функции в течение времени задержки, пока функция вызывается снова ранее, чем прошло время задержки", что не так?

Comment: Подсмотрите тут, как [заблокировать повторный вызов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457487/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5/1457498#1457498)

Comment: @SwaD, в вопросе точно такой же код что и у тебя

Comment: @Grundy По сути да, только отличается тем, что флаг расчитывается не каждый вызов функции, а 1 раз за сработанный вызов, остальные игнорируются. Возврат флага происходит так же по некоторому условию.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял из описания, то вам нужна функция, которая будет выполняться через некоторое время после вызова, а если еще раз функцию вызвали, то отменять предыдущий вызов и запускать заново.

```js
let counter = 0;
const fnс = () => {
  counter++;
};

// Каждый следующий вызов отменяет предыдущий, если он ожидает выполнения
const debounce = (fn, debounceTime) => {
  let timer;
  return function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fn, debounceTime);
  };
};

const debouncedFn = debounce(fnс, 200);
debouncedFn(); // первый вызов
setTimeout(debouncedFn, 100); // вызов через 100 мс после последнего вызова
// первый вызов был заблокирован, второй ожидает окончания таймера
setTimeout(debouncedFn, 200); // вызов через 100 мс после последнего вызова
// второй вызов был заблокирован, третий ожидает окончания таймера
setTimeout(debouncedFn, 300); // ...
setTimeout(debouncedFn, 400); // после этого вызова не следует других вызовов
// только этот вызов сработает, т.к. после него прошло 200 мс и других вызовов не было

console.log('Ждем окончания');

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('CNT', counter); // 1
}, 1000);
```

Если надо, что бы сначала вызывалась, а потом запускался таймер, не позволяющий выполнить функцию в течении некоторго времени, то фукнция должна иметь вид примерно такой:

```
const debounce = (fn, debounceTime) => {
  let isWait = false;

  return function() {
    if (!isWait) {
      isWait = true;
      fn();
      setTimeout(() => isWait = false, debounceTime);
    }
  };
};
```